# Filter out only required result in Anisble

Tags: linux, bash, ansible, grep

Given the list of hosts

```yaml
hostnames:
  - vhost.alsoworks.local
  - vhost.works.local
```

I get the certificate details but it shows me whole process output and I only need grep output on my screen how can I do that?

```yaml
  - name: sslyze - get Serial Number, it can be stored into variable
    shell: sslyze --certinfo {{ item }} | egrep 'Serial Number|Not Before|Not After'
    loop: "{{ hostnames }}"
    delegate_to : 127.0.0.1
    ignore_errors: yes
    check_mode: no
    register: part1
    
  - debug:
    msg: "{{ part1 }}"
```

The Output looks like this :

```yaml
     "msg": {
            "changed": true,
            "msg": "All items completed",
            "results": [
                {
                    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                    "changed": true,
                    "cmd": "sslyze --certinfo vhost.alsoworks.local | egrep 'Serial Number|Not Before|Not After'",
                    "delta": "0:00:00.583648",
                    "end": "2022-02-23 16:05:21.571709",
                    "failed": false,
                    "invocation": {
                        "module_args": {
                            "_raw_params": "sslyze --certinfo vhost.alsoworks.local | egrep 'Serial Number|Not Before|Not After'",
                            "_uses_shell": true,
                            "argv": null,
                            "chdir": null,
                            "creates": null,
                            "executable": null,
                            "removes": null,
                            "stdin": null,
                            "stdin_add_newline": true,
                            "strip_empty_ends": true,
                            "warn": true
                        }
                    },
                    "item": "vhost.alsoworks.local",
                    "rc": 0,
                    "start": "2022-02-23 16:05:20.988061",
                    "stderr": "",
                    "stderr_lines": [],
                    "stdout": "       Serial Number:                     1671745751113260994429\n       Not Before:                        2022-02-17\n       Not After:                         2032-02-15",
                    "stdout_lines": [
                        "       Serial Number:                     1671745751321160994429",
                        "       Not Before:                        2022-02-17",
                        "       Not After:                         2032-02-15"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
                    "changed": true,
                    "cmd": "sslyze --certinfo vhost.works.local | egrep 'Serial Number|Not Before|Not After'",
                    "delta": "0:00:00.573596",
                    "end": "2022-02-23 16:05:22.263896",
                    "failed": false,
                    "invocation": {
                        "module_args": {
                            "_raw_params": "sslyze --certinfo vhost.works.local | egrep 'Serial Number|Not Before|Not After'",
                            "_uses_shell": true,
                            "argv": null,
                            "chdir": null,
                            "creates": null,
                            "executable": null,
                            "removes": null,
                            "stdin": null,
                            "stdin_add_newline": true,
                            "strip_empty_ends": true,
                            "warn": true
                        }
                    },
                    "item": "vhost.works.local",
                    "rc": 0,
                    "start": "2022-02-23 16:05:21.690300",
                    "stderr": "",
                    "stderr_lines": [],
                    "stdout": "       Serial Number:                     1671745751326011994429\n       Not Before:                        2022-02-17\n       Not After:                         2032-02-15",
                    "stdout_lines": [
                        "       Serial Number:                     1671745751326011994429",
                        "       Not Before:                        2022-02-17",
                        "       Not After:                         2032-02-15"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi. Please edit your question and indent your yaml properly to start with. Moreover, rather than describing with words what happens, you'll have to give the exact output you get and the one you expect instead. Last, you probably want to head for the documentation of the `find` and `x509_certificate_info` modules which will help you achieve all of the above without using `shell`

Comment: @Zeitounator I have added the output. The x509 is not working somehow for me. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

For example

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        certinfo: "{{ certinfo|d({})|combine({item.0: _dict}) }}"
      loop: "{{ _hosts|zip(_certs) }}"
      vars:
        _hosts: "{{ part1.results|map(attribute='item')|list }}"
        _certs: "{{ part1.results|map(attribute='stdout_lines')|list }}"
        _dict: "{{ dict(item.1|map('split', ':')|map('map', 'trim')|list) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  certinfo:
    vhost.alsoworks.local:
      Not After: '2032-02-15'
      Not Before: '2022-02-17'
      Serial Number: '1671745751321160994429'
    vhost.works.local:
      Not After: '2032-02-15'
      Not Before: '2022-02-17'
      Serial Number: '1671745751326011994429'
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am little bit confuse. what is d({}) , _dict , whole loop thing..can you explain it to me ... because when I try to run this it gives me this error.  

FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: <zip object at 0x7f6a19aa3700>. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use q/query instead of lookup."}

Comment: You are welcome. ``d({})`` is alias for ``default({})``. All elements of the expression are available in the doc. If you don't understand something read the documentation and test the particular piece of code. Start, for example, with ``_dict``. Create ``- debug: var=_dict`` and try to understand the expression step by step (split, map, trim, dict, ...). If you have a problem  [edit] the question and make it [mre].